# How to run an outside program, passing it memory addresses to read/write into?

Tags: c++, windows, c++03

Let's say I have two programs, `Game.exe` and `Probe.exe`

Both are programs I'm authoring (this isn't a scenario where I'm trying to hack into a executable I don't own).  I want `Probe` to be run by `Game` and be given the addresses of certain global variables within `Game`, so that `Probe` can read and write to them, for debugging purposes.

What would be a safe way to run `Probe` from `Game` and give it valid addresses into `Game`'s memory it can read/write to?  If it's not possible to do this with addresses alone, what might be the least intrusive way of making this possible?

Comment: That won't work. Each process has it's own virtual address space. The memory addresses passed won't be accessible.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There are platform specific functions like `ReadProcessMemory` that OP could use. But that's not really feasible

Comment: @SombreroChicken since the OP's question is marked as `Windows`, platform-specific functions will work fine

Comment: Have you tried sharing data on ramdrive file? Game.exe writes to it, probe.exe reads from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Game.exe` can pass the desired memory addresses as command line parameters when launching `Probe.exe`.

`Probe.exe` can retrieve those memory addresses from the command line, and then use [`ReadProcessMemory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553.aspx) and [`WriteProcessMemory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674.aspx) to access them.  For that to work, `Probe.exe` will also have to obtain a `HANDLE` to the `Game.exe` process:

- `Game.exe` can pass its process ID as a command line parameter, then `Probe.exe` can pass that ID to [`OpenProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess).

Or

- `Game.exe` can use [`GetCurrentProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocess) and [`DuplicateHandle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251.aspx) to create an inheritable copy of its own `HANDLE`, and then pass that `HANDLE` value to `Probe.exe` via command line parameter, and let `Probe.exe` inherit the actual `HANDLE` object when launched (via [`CreateProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) with `bInheritHandles=TRUE`, or a [`STARTUPINFOEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/ns-winbase-_startupinfoexw) struct - see [Programmatically controlling which handles are inherited by new processes in Win32](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111216-00/?p=8873)).

That being said, a *safer* option would be to simply store the desired variables in a block of memory that both `Game.exe` and `Probe.exe` can share using [`CreateFileMapping()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga) and [`MapViewFromFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761.aspx).